# CSS precedence and !important

Tags: html, css

I have a web application which - in its automatically rendered default CSS - includes the following style:

```
body * { line-height: 1.22em; }
```

So far this is fine, but for a specific table I want to override this `line-height`. Unfortunately, this table is also automatically rendered, hence I have no influence on how it is rendered. Nevertheless, I have a `class` on this table.

So, what I am doing is add a line to my custom CSS which says:

```
.tableclassname { line-height: 1em !important; }
```

Unfortunately, this is ignored.

Does anyone have an idea why?

And, as second question: What would be the right way to tell the browser to use a `line-height` of `1em` for every element with class `tableclassname` and all subsidiary elements?

Comment: Can u post screenshot with developer tool with inspect element on the element?

Comment: Basically yes, but the issue has already been solved. Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unfortunately, this is ignored. Does anyone have an idea why?

Without seeing the markup, it is hard to be sure, but the odds are that the class is on the table.

`!important` applies only to the cascade, not to inheritance.

The table cells also match `body *`, so they don't have `line-height: inherit` and get the value from the style sheet instead of their parent.

> for every element with class tableclassname and all subsidiary elements

Use a descendant combinator, just like `body *` is using.

```
.tableclassname, 
.tableclassname * {
```